# In generic list, List.Last() throws System.IndexOutOfRangeException even after check of Count

Tags: c#, linq, wcf, indexoutofboundsexception, generic-list

I have following code at my WCF service, which is throwing System.IndexOutOfRangeException

```
Dictionary<string, List<ChunkData>> chunkDataTable = cacheManager[cacheKey] as Dictionary<string, List<ChunkData>>;
  if (!chunkDataTable.Keys.Contains(ticker))
  {
      chunkDataTable.Add(ticker, new List<ChunkData>());
  }
  List<ChunkData> listOfChunks = new List<ChunkData>();
  ChunkData lastIncompeleteChunk = null;
  if (chunkDataTable[ticker].Count > 0)
  {
      Logger.Write("Log one");  //I see this logs
  if (reqEndDate <= chunkDataTable[ticker].Last().EndDate)
  {
      //meaning we can directly take last chunk (which can be incompelete too) directly as we dont need to add further data into for now
      listOfChunks = chunkDataTable[ticker].Where
          (chunk =>
            ((chunk.StartDate >= reqStartDate && chunk.EndDate <= reqEndDate) ||      //whole chunks: which lies in between of requested start and end date
            (chunk.StartDate <= reqStartDate && reqStartDate <= chunk.EndDate) ||     //Left Most Chunk: if req start date lies within some chunk (between start and end date of chunk)
            (chunk.StartDate <= reqEndDate && reqEndDate <= chunk.EndDate)            //Right Most Chunk: if req end date lies within some chunk (between start and end date of chunk)
            )).OrderBy(x => x.EndDate).ToList();
  }
  else
  {
      listOfChunks = chunkDataTable[ticker].Where
        (chunk => !chunk.IsIncomplete &&
            ((chunk.StartDate >= reqStartDate && chunk.EndDate <= reqEndDate) ||      //whole chunks: which lies in between of requested start and end date
            (chunk.StartDate <= reqStartDate && reqStartDate <= chunk.EndDate) ||     //Left Most Chunk: if req start date lies within some chunk (between start and end date of chunk)
            (chunk.StartDate <= reqEndDate && reqEndDate <= chunk.EndDate)            //Right Most Chunk: if req end date lies within some chunk (between start and end date of chunk)
            )).OrderBy(x => x.EndDate).ToList();
      if (chunkDataTable[ticker].Last().IsIncomplete)
          lastIncompeleteChunk = chunkDataTable[ticker].Last();
  }

  if (listOfChunks != null)
      Logger.Write("Line two"); //I don't see this log
```

}

here `reqEndDate` and `reqStartDate` are coming form client computer and as per logs they are correct.
`cacheManager` is Microsoft enterprise library's cache manager

Full stack trace:

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Last[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
```

I wonder, at what point such exception possibly occuers

Comment: Exception is because of the `chunkDataTable[ticker]` not because of `.Last()`

Comment: @un-lucky you mean to way `chunkDataTable` may not contain 'ticker'?, if so: but i m able to get First log "log one"

Comment: Is it throwing it consistently or from time to time? is `cacheManager` static?

Comment: @Evk yes it is being thrown every time for particular `ticker`, no cacheManager is not static but it is holding common Cache for every request. As it is at production I cannot directly Debug it.

Comment: I'd say it's threading issue. Another thread (another WCF request for example) modifies `chunkDataTable[ticker]` collection after you checked for count (and even right in the middle of your `Last()` statement).

Comment: @Evk possible, It can be due to Reference I m taking from cache manger.Let me confirm it by creating new Dictionary out from cache manager and see.

Comment: @Evk this fix is working so far. However proper testing will be done in rush hours!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stack trace suggests that this is a threaing issue. `Last()` is implemented something like this:

```
IList<TSource> sourceList = source as IList<TSource>;
if (sourceList != null)
{
    int count = sourceList.Count;
    if (count > 0)
      return sourceList[count - 1];
}
```

So if `IEnumerable` you pass implements `IList` (like in your case), it will first save total length in a variable and then will access last element. The only way exception with your stack trace can be thrown is if number of elements in `source` was changed between `sourceList.Count` and `sourceList[count - 1]` statements, which can only be done by another thread.

If you are using shared cache - that change can be made by another WCF thread. So to fix - implement proper synchronization when working with items from your shared cache.